# Why can I not always change Target Framework in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

I just downloaded Visual Studio for Mac and for some reason in some projects I've made, I can change the target framework, but most of the time it's greyed out:

[image]

Does anyone know how to always be able to change the target framework?

Comment: What other .NET SDKs do you have installed?

Comment: I only have Microsoft.NETCore.App (2.1.0), but for the code I'm writing, I need to have Target Framework 3.5. I looked on NuGet, but I didn't see a Target Framework 3.5 listed.

Comment: If it helps, in the Solutions where I can change the target framework, there aren't any .NET SDKs listed in the Dependencies.

Comment: You cannot target .NET Framework 3.5 using Visual Studio for Mac, only .NET Core, Xamarin and possibly Mono. Only Visual Studio for Windows can target the full-fat .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had used the wrong template when I was first creating the solution. I **should** have used this one:

[image]

When used, it allows me to select the proper Target Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Visual Studio for Mac, with a .NET Core project, will only allow you to select those .NET Core target frameworks which are installed on your local machine.

The current .NET Core SDK that is installed with the Visual Studio for Mac installer includes the runtimes for .NET Core 2.1 so only 2.1 is available in the project options for the target framework.

On my machine, for example, I have 2.1, 2.0, 1.1 and 1.0 installed so I can choose all versions in the project options.

[image]

The About dialog shows you what .NET Core SDKs are installed.

[image]

You can see more .NET Core SDK information in the main Preferences dialog, as shown below:

[image]
The target frameworks available for .NET Framework projects has more options since Mono supports a wider range of framework versions.