# Resolving warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp3.0' is out of support

Tags: macos, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to build this project in Visual Studio for Mac:

https://github.com/macNetCore/CodeBook/tree/master/Chapter5/configProgram

During compilation I receive a warning:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp3.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy.

I decided to try and change the target framework in the project settings:

[image]

What I am finding is that when I select either:

- .NET 5.0
- .NET Core 3.1

And click OK and then re-display the options it has reverted to .NET Core 3.0.

In short, what steps must I take to to stop the build warning?

---

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412716/why-can-i-not-always-change-target-framework-in-visual-studio-for-mac) and I definitely have the correct SDK's installed. So I don't understand why clicking OK won't persist my choice for 3.1.

Comment: add NoWarn to csproj **<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NETSDK1138</NoWarn>** and also change Targetframework(s) directly in the csproj

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add

```
<CheckEolTargetFramework>false</CheckEolTargetFramework>
```

For an example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <CheckEolTargetFramework>false</CheckEolTargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Additionally you can refer to this post as well.
https://andrewlock.net/fixing-build-warning-netsdk1138-when-building-end-of-life-projects-with-dotnet-5/